# Access is denied when trying to CustomDevice.FromIdAsync using a Software KMDF Driver

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, inf, kmdf

I have prepared a KMDF driver meant to be accessed by a UWP using the guidelines found within MSDN ([HSA for Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/hardware-support-app--hsa--steps-for-driver-developers), [HSA for UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/hardware-support-app--hsa--steps-for-app-developers))

The UWP App I used is the `CustomCapability` example found under [Universal Windows Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomCapability)
The KMDF is a sample driver with only the `DriverEntry, Unload, and EvtDeviceAdd` implemented. Also, the driver has been installed, and is visible in Device Manager, but there is no actual/external device plugged in.

In the UWP App, I can see the Sample Driver from the device watcher. However, when attempting to connect/open the driver using :

```
var device = await CustomDevice.FromIdAsync(Id, DeviceAccessMode.Read, DeviceSharingMode.Exclusive);
```

An exception `System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll` is being thrown 
as seen below:

[image: exception]

I have matched the required information that needs to get across both apps, and I have gone and tried this one out with the assumption that the `SCCD` does not require signing if it is only meant to run in development mode.

Aside from the SCCD configuration, I have also tried adding a `<DeviceCapability>` for the class interface of the driver, as well as for `lowLevel` devices, but it did not seem to do anything related to the exception.

I don't see any other places for issues aside from the SCCD and the INF file, but I would like to show them just in case I missed something:

`SCCD:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomCapabilityDescriptor xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2016/sccd" xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2016/sccd">
    <CustomCapabilities>
        <CustomCapability Name="microsoft.firmwareRead_cw5n1h2txyewy"></CustomCapability> <!-- this one is not used by the way -->
        <CustomCapability Name="microsoft.hsaTestCustomCapability_q536wpkpf5cy2"></CustomCapability> 
    </CustomCapabilities>
    <AuthorizedEntities>
        <AuthorizedEntity AppPackageFamilyName="Microsoft.SDKSamples.CustomCapability.CS_8wekyb3d8bbwe" CertificateSignatureHash="1db5ceeaa4c97c6f6e91c0ce76830361776c64635ecfecdb2f157ca818ae3b69"></AuthorizedEntity>
  </AuthorizedEntities>
    <Catalog>xxxx</Catalog>
</CustomCapabilityDescriptor>
```

`INF Strings and Interface section:`

```
[Strings]
SPSVCINST_ASSOCSERVICE= 0x00000002
ManufacturerName="Samples" ;TODO: Replace with your manufacturer name
ClassName="Samples" ; TODO: edit ClassName
DiskName = "Samples_Driver Installation Disk"
Samples_Driver.DeviceDesc = "Samples_Driver Device"
Samples_Driver.SVCDESC = "Samples_Driver Service"
GUID_DEVINTERFACE_OSRUSBFX2="573E8C73-0CB4-4471-A1BF-FAB26C31D384"
DEVPKEY_DeviceInterface_UnrestrictedAppCapabilities="026e516e-b814-414b-83cd-856d6fef4822"
CustomCapability="microsoft.hsaTestCustomCapability_q536wpkpf5cy2"

;
;----------------- Interface Section ----------------------
;
[WDMPNPB003_Device.NT.Interfaces] 
AddInterface= {%GUID_DEVINTERFACE_OSRUSBFX2%},,AddInterfaceSection 

[AddInterfaceSection] 
AddProperty= AddInterfaceSection.AddProps 

[AddInterfaceSection.AddProps] 
; DEVPKEY_DeviceInterface_UnrestrictedAppCapabilities 
{%DEVPKEY_DeviceInterface_UnrestrictedAppCapabilities%}, 8, 0x2012,, %CustomCapability%
```

Comment: Hi, In the `SCCD` file, you have two `CustomCapability`, you can try to add an `AuthorizedEntity` to the SCCD file. If that doesn't work, you can troubleshoot according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/hardware-support-app--hsa--steps-for-app-developers#troubleshooting)

Comment: I added another `AuthorizedEntity`, but with the same `CertificateSignatureHash` as the existing one (the SHA-256 signature hash generated from the uwp app cert) and it did not seem to work. I have also tried the troubleshooting approach mentioned in that link, which confirms that my `PackageFamilyName` is correct, but also did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem on the INF file. The section labeled `Interface Section` has been copied directly from the [HSA for Drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/hardware-support-app--hsa--steps-for-driver-developers) guide by Microsoft. The modifications done were only those that were explicitly written within the guidelines.

The INF snippet below describes the starting point of the interface section:

```
[WDMPNPB003_Device.NT.Interfaces] 
AddInterface= {zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz},,AddInterfaceSection
```

What the guide did not explicitly mention is that we would have to replace `WDMPNPB003_Device` with your own `Driver_name/Root namespace`.

A petty mistake, but will most likely be what driver development new comers will encounter.