# UWP application use "CustomDevice.FromIdAsync" access KMDF driver is denied

Tags: c#, uwp

> I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047977/access-is-denied-when-trying-to-customdevice-fromidasync-using-a-software-kmdf-d), but it probably didn't help me much.

I'm learning to access drive devices via UWP, in the first two days, the program was **working fine**, but today, UWP error close when open device, the error message is **"Access is denied. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005"**

I don't know if something was modified during the update process that caused this problem. I only have a snapshot of the virtual machine that can open the drive device. On this snapshot, when I update the UWP application, I can also open the drive device, but after update the driver, the UWP application can no longer open the driver device.

Does this mean the problem is with the driver?

After that, I created a new KMDF project and a UWP project, only printed some information, and the same error occurred after installing to the virtual machine.

It is worth noting that when I saw the UWP access to the drive device in DbgView, the `EvtDeviceFileCreate` event callback was triggered, but the `EvtDeviceClose` event callback was triggered immediately, I think, there should be no problem with the device interface.

Also, in the beginning, I used the device manager to "Add legacy hardware" to load the driver, then I tried to install the driver using `devcon`, both can install the driver, but it seems to be slightly different, I am not sure if this also It will have an impact, although both installation methods currently do not solve the problem I am encountering.

Below are some settings for UWP app and drivers.

Register device interface and add custom capability:

In this part, I refer to Microsoft's official sample [kmdf_fx2](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/kmdf_fx2).

```
    WDFSTRING symbolicLinkString = NULL;
    UNICODE_STRING symbolicLinkName = SymbolicName;
    DEVPROP_BOOLEAN isRestricted;
    status = WdfDeviceCreateDeviceInterface(
        hDevice,
        (LPGUID)&GUID_INTERFACE_HSADRVSAMPLE1,
        NULL); // Reference String
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        KdPrint(("WdfDeviceCreateDeviceInterface Fail\n"));
        goto Error;
    }
    if (g_pIoSetDeviceInterfacePropertyData != NULL) {
        status = WdfStringCreate(NULL,
            WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,
            &symbolicLinkString);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            KdPrint(("WdfStringCreate Fail\n"));
            goto Error;
        }
        status = WdfDeviceRetrieveDeviceInterfaceString(
            hDevice,
            (LPGUID)&GUID_INTERFACE_HSADRVSAMPLE1,
            NULL,
            symbolicLinkString);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            KdPrint(("WdfDeviceRetrieveDeviceInterfaceString Fail\n"));
            goto Error;
        }
        WdfStringGetUnicodeString(symbolicLinkString, &symbolicLinkName);
        isRestricted = DEVPROP_TRUE;
        status = g_pIoSetDeviceInterfacePropertyData(
            &symbolicLinkName,
            &DEVPKEY_DeviceInterface_Restricted,
            0,
            0,
            DEVPROP_TYPE_BOOLEAN,
            sizeof(isRestricted),
            &isRestricted);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            KdPrint(("g_pIoSetDeviceInterfacePropertyData Fail\n"));
            goto Error;
        }

#if defined(NTDDI_WIN10_RS2) && (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN10_RS2)
        static const wchar_t customCapabilities[] = L"ColinTest.HSADrvSample_2022051717171\0";
        status = g_pIoSetDeviceInterfacePropertyData(
            &symbolicLinkName,
            &DEVPKEY_DeviceInterface_UnrestrictedAppCapabilities,
            0,
            0,
            DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING_LIST,
            sizeof(customCapabilities),
            (PVOID)&customCapabilities);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            KdPrint(("g_pIoSetDeviceInterfacePropertyData Fail\n"));
            goto Error;
        }
#endif

        WdfObjectDelete(symbolicLinkString);
    }
Error:
    if (symbolicLinkString != NULL) {
        WdfObjectDelete(symbolicLinkString);
    }
```

Driver INF：

```
;
; HSADrvSample1.inf
;

[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=Test ; TODO: edit Class
ClassGuid={160303BD-D84C-4819-B962-9B1BDBB52310} ; TODO: edit ClassGuid
Provider=%ManufacturerName%
CatalogFile=HSADrvSample1.cat
DriverVer = 05/19/2022,9.21.50.151
PnpLockDown=1

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 12
HSADrvSample1_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles = 11

; ================= Class section =====================

[ClassInstall32]
Addreg=SampleClassReg

[SampleClassReg]
HKR,,,0,%ClassName%
HKR,,Icon,,-5

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskName%,,,""

[SourceDisksFiles]
HSADrvSample1.sys  = 1,,
WdfCoInstaller01011.dll=1 ; make sure the number matches with SourceDisksNames

;*****************************************
; Install Section
;*****************************************

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NTamd64

[Standard.NTamd64]
%HSADrvSample1.DeviceDesc%=HSADrvSample1_Device, Root\HSADrvSample1 ; TODO: edit hw-id

[HSADrvSample1_Device.NT]
CopyFiles=Drivers_Dir

[Drivers_Dir]
HSADrvSample1.sys

;-------------- Service installation
[HSADrvSample1_Device.NT.Services]
AddService = HSADrvSample1,%SPSVCINST_ASSOCSERVICE%, HSADrvSample1_Service_Inst

; -------------- HSADrvSample1 driver install sections
[HSADrvSample1_Service_Inst]
DisplayName    = %HSADrvSample1.SVCDESC%
ServiceType    = 1               ; SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
StartType      = 3               ; SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl   = 1               ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
ServiceBinary  = %12%\HSADrvSample1.sys

;
;--- HSADrvSample1_Device Coinstaller installation ------
;

[HSADrvSample1_Device.NT.CoInstallers]
AddReg=HSADrvSample1_Device_CoInstaller_AddReg
CopyFiles=HSADrvSample1_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles

[HSADrvSample1_Device_CoInstaller_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000, "WdfCoInstaller01011.dll,WdfCoInstaller"

[HSADrvSample1_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles]
WdfCoInstaller01011.dll

[HSADrvSample1_Device.NT.Wdf]
KmdfService =  HSADrvSample1, HSADrvSample1_wdfsect
[HSADrvSample1_wdfsect]
KmdfLibraryVersion = 1.11

[Strings]
SPSVCINST_ASSOCSERVICE= 0x00000002
ManufacturerName="Colin" ;TODO: Replace with your manufacturer name
ClassName="Test" ; TODO: edit ClassName
DiskName = "HSADrvSample1 Installation Disk"
HSADrvSample1.DeviceDesc = "HSADrvSample1 Device"
HSADrvSample1.SVCDESC = "HSADrvSample1 Service"
```

SCCD File：

The file is configured as per the official documentation[Hardware Support App (HSA): Steps for App Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devapps/hardware-support-app--hsa--steps-for-app-developers), the file is already set to `content`.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomCapabilityDescriptor xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2018/sccd" xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2018/sccd">
    <CustomCapabilities>
        <CustomCapability Name="ColinTest.HSADrvSample_2022051717171"></CustomCapability>
    <AuthorizedEntities>
        <AuthorizedEntity AppPackageFamilyName="Colin.HSA.APP_4a8dxf1xdwf12" CertificateSignatureHash="2d6e4f1418bc13447bb8c10067d0af418cb8a2f9e14c014e03a1e0ec811735af"></AuthorizedEntity>
    </AuthorizedEntities>
    <Catalog>FFFF</Catalog>
</CustomCapabilityDescriptor>
```

Part of Package.appxmanifest：

```html
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
      <uap4:CustomCapability Name="ColinTest.HSADrvSample_2022051717171"/>
  </Capabilities>
```

Part of UWP Code：

```
string selector = CustomDevice.GetDeviceSelector(DeviceInterfaceGuid);
            DeviceInformationCollection enumDevice = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
            string DeviceID = enumDevice[0].Id;
            try
            {
                CustomDevice Device = await CustomDevice.FromIdAsync(DeviceID, DeviceAccessMode.ReadWrite, DeviceSharingMode.Shared);
                if (null != Device)
                {
                    Note.Text = "Open successfully";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Note.Text = "Failed to open!" + ex.Message;
            }
```

I would like to know at which step am I getting the error? How to solve?

---

> At the suggestion of **@Nico Zhu - MSFT**, I checked the `CustomCapabilityName` again.

There are three places in my code related to `CustomCapabilityName`, but they are all the **same**.
To test if the problem lies here, I **reset** the name.

1. Driver Code

```
static const wchar_t customCapabilities[] = L"Test.hsaTestCustomCapability_1653011401000\0";
```

2. CustomCapability.SCCD

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomCapabilityDescriptor xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2018/sccd" xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2018/sccd">
    <CustomCapabilities>
        <CustomCapability Name="Test.hsaTestCustomCapability_1653011401000"></CustomCapability>
    </CustomCapabilities>
    <AuthorizedEntities AllowAny="true"/>
    <Catalog>0000</Catalog>
</CustomCapabilityDescriptor>
```

3. Package.appxmanifest

```html
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
      <uap4:CustomCapability Name="Test.hsaTestCustomCapability_1653011401000"/>
  </Capabilities>
```

After that, I **uninstalled** the previously installed apps and drivers, **restarted** and installed the latest version of the program, but I still **can't access** it.

My SDK and WDK version is **10.0.19041.0**, test machine OS version is **Windows 10 Pro Build 19041.vb_release.191206-1406**

Comment: Have your tried to roll driver version back？

Comment: it's hard to say for drive problem. if the problem only occurs after drive update, it's more related with hardware. Do test with other machine to exclude OS problem?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I remember I did, but I tried it again just to make sure it was right. Rolling back the driver version in a virtual machine that can access the driver device will still be accessible, but will not be accessible after uninstalling the driver and reinstalling it. The fallback driver is still inaccessible in other virtual machines.

Comment: You test in the virtual machine ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I tested both on two virtual machines and one physical machine, but both are inaccessible.

Comment: Have you treid  [official code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/CustomCapability) for kmdf_fx2

Comment: If the exception is access KMDF driver is denied, and the problem is likely to be in the capability, please check if `ColinTest.HSADrvSample_2022051717171` is correct value

Comment: I have tried to replace the driver part in this UWP application with my own driver, but it is also inaccessible.Maybe I should try using kmdf_fx2?

Comment: OK, I'll check it again. But if this is the problem, why does my program work correctly in the first place?

Comment: I'm afraid it updated the capablilty name value after you update the drvier.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I checked my `CustomCapability` and it has the same name in the three parts where it is used. Still thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I made a low-level mistake, the function `g_pIoSetDeviceInterfacePropertyData` that sets the device interface properties needs to be set in the `DriverEntry`.
But I didn't, which caused the `CustomCapabilityName` I set to not take effect.

```
    UNICODE_STRING funcName;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&funcName, L"IoSetDeviceInterfacePropertyData");
    g_pIoSetDeviceInterfacePropertyData = (PFN_IO_SET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_PROPERTY_DATA)(ULONG_PTR)
        MmGetSystemRoutineAddress(&funcName);
```

However, it is still an unsolved mystery why the driver works properly in the most initial version...